# changing color for the square textfield

Tags: java, swing, colors, background

I'm trying to create a layout that would take 3 RGB colors and change the background of the textfield but I'm not able to do so.

```
package Quizzes_practice;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class quiz3 extends JFrame{
    private JPanel up; 
    private JPanel down; 
    private JPanel left; // as mother container 
    private JPanel right;


    private JLabel font_size; 
    private JLabel color_val;
    private JLabel r;
    private JLabel g;
    private JLabel b;



    private JTextField font_text;
    private JTextField r_text;
    private JTextField g_text;
    private JTextField b_text;
    private JLabel color_text;
    private JTextField red; // the big square


    private JCheckBox bold;
    private JCheckBox italic;


    private JRadioButton fg;
    private JRadioButton bg;
    private JRadioButton reset;
    private ButtonGroup gorup;

    //private JPanel container; // this will sit in the left corner
    private JPanel panel1; // for each row one of these
    private JPanel panel2;
    private JPanel panel3;
    private JPanel panel4;

    private JPanel center;





    public quiz3(){
        JFrame myframe = new JFrame();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // general layout
        JPanel up = new JPanel();
        JPanel down  = new JPanel();
        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        JPanel right = new JPanel();

        // adding components

        // adding the main 4 panels to the their positions

        // panel left will be the container
        JLabel font_size = new JLabel("Font Size ");
        JLabel r = new JLabel("R");
        JLabel g = new JLabel("G");
        JLabel b = new JLabel("B");

        myhandler handler = new myhandler();

        JTextField font_text = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField r_text = new JTextField(4);
        r_text.addActionListener(handler);
        JTextField g_text = new JTextField(4);
        g_text.addActionListener(handler);
        JTextField b_text = new JTextField(4);
        b_text.addActionListener(handler);

        JCheckBox bold = new JCheckBox("Bold");
        JCheckBox italic = new JCheckBox("Italic");


        JRadioButton fg = new JRadioButton("Foreground");
        JRadioButton bg = new JRadioButton("Background");
        JRadioButton reset = new JRadioButton("Reset");
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();



        //JPanel center = new JPanel();
        red = new JTextField(); // text field that I want to change its color 
        //center.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        //center.add(red);
        ///red.setBackground(Color.RED);

        add(up, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(down, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(left, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(red, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel ();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel ();
        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel ();
        JPanel panel4 = new JPanel ();
        // adding compnents to the frame 
        up.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        up.add(font_size);
        up.add(font_text);
        up.add(bold);
        up.add(italic);

        down.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        //down.add(group);
        group.add(fg);
        group.add(bg);
        group.add(reset);

        down.add(fg);
        down.add(bg);
        down.add(reset);


        JLabel color_text = new JLabel("Font size");
        panel1.add(color_text);
        panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel2.add(r);
        panel2.add(r_text);

        panel3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel3.add(g);
        panel3.add(g_text);

        panel4.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel4.add(b);
        panel4.add(b_text);

        left.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,0));
        left.add(panel1);
        left.add(panel2);
        left.add(panel3);
        left.add(panel4);


    }

    private class myhandler implements ActionListener{
        int red1;
        int blue1;
        int green1;
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){

            if(event.getSource()== r_text){
                String a = event.getActionCommand();
                int a2 = Integer.parseInt(a);
                Color mycolor = new Color(a2);
                red.setBackground(mycolor);


            }

            if(event.getSource()== b_text){
                String a = event.getActionCommand();
                int a2 = Integer.parseInt(a);
                Color mycolor = new Color(a2);
                red.setBackground(mycolor);
                }

            if(event.getSource()== g_text){
                String a = event.getActionCommand();
                int a2 = Integer.parseInt(a);
                Color mycolor = new Color(a2);
                red.setBackground(mycolor);

            }
            else {System.out.println("error!");}







        }
    }

}
```

I'm not getting an error, it's just not happening, the condition I believe is incorrect

Comment: Try debugging your code and checking the variables line by line. Do that and see if you can find out where exactly the code is behaving differently than you expect.

Comment: Add some log trace, or at least some `System.out.println("Entering in if...");` to check the flow

Comment: Your Layout is completely wrong. Can you share a screenshot/picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) your `JTextField` variables. Replace

```
JTextField r_text = new JTextField(4);
```

with

```
r_text = new JTextField(4);
```

The same applys to the other color components.

Aside: Consider using `JColorChooser`. Read [How to Use Color Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, it was a quiz question and I'm trying to re-do it by myself hoping to practice and solve it. Thanks

Comment: +1, @N.J, don't forget to accept the answer when it answers your question so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: Thank you all for the reply that was helpful. I went back to the book and saw my silly mistakes :)